# how to set background image on flutter

Tags: flutter, background

This is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
      - images/img_rectangle1.jpg
```

I have established an assets folder and included it with my.png picture; but, I am experiencing difficulty with the widgets.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("Korean vocabulary related to traits"),
      centerTitle: false,
      backgroundColor:  const Color(0xFFEC74C8),
    ),
    body: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: koreanNameList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                KoreanItem item = koreanNameList[index];
                return Draggable<KoreanItem>(
                    data: item,
                    dragAnchorStrategy: pointerDragAnchorStrategy,
                    feedback: KoreanNameCard(item: item),
                    child: KoreanNameCard(item: item));
              },
            )),
        Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: englishanswers.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return buildEnglishanswerColumn(englishanswers[index]);
              },
            )),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Where exactly should the container that holds the background picture be placed, then?

I have tried to use

```
AssetImage
```

but it is not showing on my app.

Comment: Do you have an image example you wanted to to put bg picture on whole page or a item widget?

Comment: big picture on whole page https://www.figma.com/file/lhSUIPSfXY635RniYF4w6s/draggable?node-id=1%3A3&t=7oVVHj3nKmjulJxC-1

Comment: What exactly the problem? Are you getting an error ? Pls check it on your debug console

Comment: The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/img_rectangle1.png

Comment: is it for the reason of png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **specify** the **assets** on **`pubspec.yaml`**

Flutter uses the pubspec.yaml file, located at the root of your project, to identify assets required by an app.

Here is an example:

> ```
> flutter:
>   assets:
>     - assets/images/background.png
> ```

To include all assets under a directory, specify the directory name with the / character at the end:

> ```
> flutter:
>   assets:
>     - assets/
>     - assets/images/
> ```

sample using image asset

```
Container(
  height: double.infinity,
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage("assets/splash/background.png"),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  child: const Center(
    child: Text(
      'Hello World!',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
);
```

**Reference**: [Adding assets and images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Comment: flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
assets:
  - assets/img_rectangle1.jpg

Comment: still unable to load the bg pic.

Comment: Can you add some portion of your pubspec.yaml file on your question?

Comment: edit my answer with the pubscpec.yaml

Comment: make sure you indented right the properties on .yaml file

Comment: You may read the reference link on my answer to understand how adding assets & images works. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!!!! I have manage to delete the assets and the background picture is shown!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For setting an image as the background, use this Container widget as the body of your Scaffold.

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage("assets/images/image.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
  ),

  child: child
)
```

Replace image.jpg with your image name.